# How to figure out missing dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

```
./src/app/story-upload/story-upload.ts
17:18-46 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/CommonJsRequireContextDependency.js:27:4)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
    at Compilation.finish (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
    at /home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/home/themadhatter/sites/brandyd2-explore/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

The error above is what shows after I add my **story-upload** component in my very basic Angular App, which I generated from the angular-cli (latest version). I have included WebPack in it, and I think it's webpack that needs some dependencies that I am missing.

I need to know what dependency is missing, and I can't seem to be able to figure it out from this error. How do I figure out what dependencies I need for a particular component?

**This is app/story-upload/story-upload.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
var storyUploadTemplate = "./story-upload.html";
@Component({
  selector: 'story-upload',
  templateUrl: storyUploadTemplate
})
export class StoryUpload {}
```

**This is app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**app/app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoryUpload } from './story-upload';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StoryUpload
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**src/main.ts:**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**.. and my webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills',
    vendor:    './src/vendor',
    main:      './src/main'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/,   loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.html/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'].reverse(), minChunks: Infinity }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 }
  },

  node: {
    global: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false,
    clearTimeout: true,
    setTimeout: true
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Could you post the content of `story-upload.ts`as well?

Comment: Done that, and a few more files that I thought could help debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using variable `storyUploadTemplate` at templateUrl, rather than the string `"./story-upload.html"` is probably what gives you the error

```
@Component({
  selector: 'story-upload',
  templateUrl: storyUploadTemplate
})
```